# Request an external streaming JSON feed in Node

Tags: node.js, json, request, streaming

In `Node.js` I'm using `stream-chain` and `stream-json` to request streaming feeds from local and remote resources. Below works for local resources, but how to modify it, to allow also for external resources? Do I need to download the file first or?

```
const fs              = require('fs');
const { chain }       = require('stream-chain');
const Pick            = require('stream-json/filters/Pick');
const { streamArray } = require('stream-json/streamers/StreamArray');

const path = './feed.json'; // External URL or local file

const pipeline = chain([
    fs.createReadStream(path),
    Pick.withParser({ filter: 'products', once: true }), // Custom: modify feed
    streamArray(),
    data => data
]);

pipeline.on('data', () => {
    counter++;
    console.log(data);
});
pipeline.on('error', error => console.log(error));
pipeline.on('end', () => console.log(`Found ${counter} entries`));
```

Comment: You mean an http url with a stream feed?

Comment: what are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The question boils down to having a readable stream through network and processing it on run time.

I don't think this is going to work, and, finally you have to download the file only, and process as local file.

There are ways to get the file from network:

```
var remotePath = "https://....."
https.get(remotePath, response => {
  var stream = response.pipe(file);

  stream.on("finish", function() {
    console.log("done");
  });
});
```

or using request"

```
request(remotePath).pipe(fs.createWriteStream('./remoteFeed.json'))
```

But at end there is no readable stream with run time processing.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to download the file and process manually. You can use `request()` function to get online file. But i agree with `Suryapratap`. but you can also write to a file and read from same file and continue with your program. example

```
    request("https://reqres.in/api/users",(err, res, body)=>{
        if(err) console.log(err);
    const objectBody = JSON.parse(body)
    fs.writeFile('justtest.json',JSON.stringify(objectBody),err=>{
     if(err) throw err;
    })

     const readable = fs.createReadStream('./justtest.json', "UTF-8");

     readable.on("data", data =>{
           payload = JSON.parse(data);
           console.log(payload);
      } )

 })
```

you can now use object to your stuff.